# Display image depending of result in MySQL query, using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change a value depending a result.
In this case, if my row "status" is "Active" I want to put something like that in a table:

```
<td>'.$row['register_status'].'</td>
<td>'if($row['status']=='Active'){print "<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true" style="color:orange"></span>";}'</td>
<td>'.$row['register_status'].'</td>
```

What is wrong?

**Edit:** Sorry. I did not put all code. Here starting my array and I put with quotes your code but can't run

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $number = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
            $data .= '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['register_status'].'</td>
            <td>'
            if($row['status']=='Active')
            {
            echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true" style="color:orange"></span>';
            }
            '</td>
        </tr>';
            $number++;
    }
}
else
{
    // records now found 
    $data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">Records not found!</td></tr>';
}

$data .= '</table>';

echo $data;
```

Comment: many things are wrong. what is the error you are trying to fix?

Comment: And edit your question instead of posting it as answers.